# ESP8266 Arduino 2.2 TFT ILI9341

Tags: arduino, touchscreen, lcd, esp8266

I recently got one TFT LCD from aliexpress which supports SPI and uses ILI9341.

This is the one.[TTT ILI9341](http://m.aliexpress.com/item/32508607290.html?productId=32508607290&productSubject=Wholesale-1PC-2-2-Inch-240-320-Dots-SPI-TFT-LCD-Serial-Port-Module-Display-ILI9341&tracelog=wwwdetail2mobilesitedetail)

I have the ESP8266 EspressoLite 1 board, and I am using ESP8266 Arduino. (https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino)

I made the following connection :

> I made the following connection : SCK #14, MOSI #13, MISO #12 and CS, #4, DC #5,RESET #0

and used the example graphicTest (which is available in the Adafruit_ILI9341-master folder) . I was able to make the display work for a few seconds. In the graphic test, once the line test starts my ESP8266 gets restarted. This was getting repeated .

In my existing project, I used the following code to just show some messages :

```
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(4, 5, 13, 14, 0, 12);
  tft.begin()
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_GREEN);  tft.setTextSize(4);
  tft.println(message);
```

The message is shown once a response is sent back from ESP. This works for a couple of times and then it again gets stuck and reboots.

I am not sure whether I am using the optimised library for ESP8266 for this LCD or whether there is any as such.

I read in forums and could see that there were some adafruit libraries in the ESP8266 Arduino but now that it is not available and only some TFT_Touch_Shield_V2 are present.

Has anyone faced the same issue or can tell me a better way to make this display work with ESP8266 Arduino.

Thanks in advance. !!!

Comment: Just a quick check to make sure: Does this chip have a hardware watchdog and are you either disabling it or resetting it appropriately?

Comment: Could you please post the serial output, exceptions, and reboot messages? The chip will log the reset reason, exception (if any), and other information each time it reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Even i had somewhat the same problem.
There's a library called 'UTFT' which works fine on the device. Try using the library. Thats the best for esp and ILI9341.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try using delay() or yield() functions in between.
The esp8266 may restart itself due to the watchdog when a loop a takes long time to process.